# Help identifying SARIMA model - work is shown

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

I´m trying find the best model that can predict the next 12-36 month of Goverment Budgetery Expenseses usingg data from January 1997 to January 2021.

My data looks like this:
[image]

I transform the data since variance is increasing through time, I run boxcox and because it returns 0.02037367 I choose to use log transformation. Now data looks like this:

```
Gastos1_lg = log(Gastos1)
```

[image]

Looking at ACF and PACF theres a trend ocurring every 12 months and it doesn´t goes to 0. I belive I have to take a difference.

[image]

This is how it looks taking a difference.

```
Gastos1_lg_d1 = diff(Gastos1_lg)
```

[image]

The stationary componente is more obvious so I took another difference and added lag 12, here are ACF and PACF:

```
Gastos1_lg_d1_la12 = diff(Gastos1_lg_d1, lag=12)
```

[image]

I dont see a thing besides that there´s something happening every 12 months.
Checking if I´m not taking too many difference I run SD and it seems not to be the case:

```
> standev(Gastos1_lg) 
[1] 0.992665 
> standev(Gastos1_lg_d1) 
[1] 0.7557841 
> standev(Gastos1_lg_d1_la12) 
[1] 0.03565512
```

I belive that finding the best model its not an exact science and that alot of expertise is in play so maybe theres somethig that I´m missing? Please let me know if thats the case.

Comment: I would trust `auto.arima()` from the `forecast` package *much more* than running the Box-Jenkins methodology by hand. It will attempt to set the best Box-Cox transformation parameter. detect your seasonality and try to find the best model using information criteria. Any specific reason why you don't use it?

Comment: @StephanKolassa because I didn't know that existed, no youtube video nor guide on time series mentioned. Thank you, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Good, so you learned something! I very much recommend the `forecast` package and `auto.arima()`, it's built by some of the leading experts in time series forecasting. See also [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/) (Hyndman is the lead author of the `forecast` package).

Comment: @StephanKolassa `forecast::auto.arima` functionality for finding the Box-Cox transformation parameter is off by default, presumably because it was added much later (version 8.3 I think). So, I would say "can attempt" rather than "will attempt".